# Knockout.JS Observable Array via AJAX bound to DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to fill my view model with some drop down options from the database. I want to keep track of the selected object because it has properties on it that I am using in a custom binding elsewhere.

I initialize the observable with a "blank" value so that it's properly set when the binding occurs and my custom binding works. Once the server responds, I morph the data to an observable array and the drop down list displays the options.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jq_fade = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};

function Firm(id, name, outsideCounsel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.outsideCounsel = outsideCounsel;
}

function RequestViewModel() {
    var self = this,
        ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;


    self.firm = ko.observable(new Firm(-1, "", false));

    $.post(ajaxAddress + 'LoadFirms', function (data) {
        var mappedFirms = $.map(data.d, function (item) {
            return new Firm(item.OrganizationLookupID, item.OrganizationLookupName, item.IsExternalCounselFirm);
        });
        self.availableFirms(mappedFirms);
        self.firm(self.availableFirms()[0]);
    });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    model = new RequestViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<span data-bind="jq_fade: firm().outsideCounsel">
    Outside Counsel
    <input type="text" id="outsideCounsel" data-bind="value: outsideCounsel" />
</span>
```

I want that DIV to show only if the selected firm is an outside counsel. If remove the line `data-bind="jq_fade: firm().outsideCounsel`, everything works fine. If I make the `$.post()` calls synchronously, it works. I'm thinking it's something wrong with my `init` function in `jq_fade`.

The error I receive is:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'outsideCounsel' of undefined;
>   Bindings value: jq_fade: firm().outsideCounsel()

I understand what Knockout is telling me, I'm just not sure how `firm()` can ever be `undefined` because I set up an initial value.

Comment: Are you sure the server returns any data? If it's not then this line self.firm(self.availableFirms()[0]); may reset self.firm to undefined

Comment: You may have to specify "json" as a last parameter to $.post.

Comment: Yes I am sure the server is returning data. You're right about specifying "json." I'm doing that further up in the page though with an `$.ajaxSetup()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're binding `availableFirms()` to a dropdownlist, I'm assuming you've also bound `firm()` to the same list so that when another is selected from the list, `firm()` gets automatically updated and all your bindings update automatically.

If this is the case, you do not need to set `firm()` at all as it will be set to the first element in the dropdownlist anyway.

See example 3 here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

```
var viewModel = {
    availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
        new country("UK", 65000000),
        new country("USA", 320000000),
        new country("Sweden", 29000000)
    ]),
    selectedCountry : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
};
```

Try it like above without specifically setting `firm()` and see if it errors again